# Can't figure out where the error is coming from (debugger says segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The program compiles normally, debugger points to this function (3rd line):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> g = {{0,1,1},
                          {1,0,0},
                          {1,0,0}};
vector<char> used;

void dfs (int v) {
    used[v] = true;
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = g[v].begin(); i!=g[v].end(); i++)
        if (!used[*i])
            dfs (*i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    dfs(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Exits with return code 1

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Are you sure values in the vector are valid indexes for `used`?

Comment: Probably a stack overflow due to recursion. How big is your container?

Comment: Is the vector used big enough to fit any value of *i? When you say 3rd line you the if of the for loop before? If it is the for loop, same question, is g big enough to fit any value of v?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; the bug is probably in the code not provided.  This will probably help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Just add your minimal example to your Question. Code in comments is nearly unreadable.

Comment: The vector `used` is empty. Any indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: At line `used[v] = true;` the `used` is empty vector. It throws an exception if you try to access an element with the index which is out of bounds.

Comment: By the way, if you want a vector of `true` and `false` values, why not `std::vector<bool>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing

```
vector <char> used;
```

You are creating an empty vector, so accessing any element of it will invoke undefined behavior (program can crash, continue, do whatever).

Consider something like

```
vector <char> used(2, 0);
```

Where you create two elements initialized to 0.

Secondly, given that C++ has `bool`as a type, you might want to consider using `vector<bool>` . This type has issues, but in your case it seems like a good fit, please look at https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool